# Powershell import-csv a csv with no headers ~1200 columns

Tags: powershell, csv

I have a csv file with no header row (it is actually only 1 row) and about 1200 columns.
I need to import the csv but if I run it import-csv it treats the first column as headers so I get nothing. any way to do this without typing 1200 headers in? Some of the items have commas in the columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can fake the headers. This does mean you need to reference each property to access the value.

```
$headers = 1..1200
$data = Import-Csv file.csv -Header $headers
```

Each data row (non-header row) is read into an array (`$data`), which starts its index at 0. This would mean data row 1 column 1 is accessed by `$data[0].1`. Data row 2 and column 4 would be `$data[0].4`. If there were a data row 5 and column 900, it would be `$data[4].900`.

If you only want to see the CSV data without the headers, you can do the following:

```
$data | ConvertTo-Csv -NoType | Select -Skip 1
```

Comment: But how about displaying the columns? When you will run `Import-Csv file.csv -Header $headers` then it will show `1..1200` as headers. There is a possible workaround I have thought `Import-Csv file.csv -Header $headers | Out-String | Set-Content temp.txt; Get-Content temp.txt | Select-Object -Skip 3` will display without headers, but the output will be in plain string. So there is no good solution for displaying columns.

Comment: @WasifHasan, if you only want the data row as a string, you can simply `$data | ConvertTo-Csv -NoType | Select -Skip 1`

Comment: This answer plus your comment is exactly what I needed thanks @AdminOfThings